# Query to get the document number associated with the passed ID is not working

Tags: laravel

After a user did a registration in a conference the createProforma() is called and this code is executed to insert in the proformas table the generated proforma number and the registration id associated with that proforma:

```php
DB::table('proformas')->insert([
    'proforma_number' => $proformaNumber,
    'registration_id' => $regID,
    'created_at' => date(now())
]);
```

Then I have a method getProforma() in other controller and in this method is necessary to get the proforma number associated with the passed registration id ($regID), so I have this query:

```php
$proformaNumber = $user->registrations()->proforma()->where('registration_id', $regId);
```

But it shows an error:

```php
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::proforma()
```

Do you know what is the error?

Registration model has this:

```php
public function proforma()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Proforma');
}
```

The proforma model has this:

```php
public function registration()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
}
```

Proforma table structure: `id, proforma_number, registration_id`

Comment: Why not `$user->registrations()->with(["proforma"])->where("registration_id", $regId)->get();`? You'd end up with a Collection of `Registration` models with an attached `Proforma`.

Comment: Thanks, like that appears "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'registration_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `registrations` where `registrations`.`user_that_did_registration` = 2 and `registrations`.`user_that_did_registration` is not null and `registration_id` = 1)
".

Comment: Oh sorry, should be just `->where("id", $regId);`, since you're querying the `registrations` table.

Comment: Thanks like that  dd($proformaNumber); shows: "
Collection {#290 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Registration {#288 ▼
      #relations: array:1 [▼
          #attributes: array:5 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "proforma_number" => 002
            "registration_id" => 2
          ]
        }
      ]
      ...
    }
  ]
}

". Now to get the proforma_number, with dd($proformaNumber->registration->proforma); shows "Property [registration] does not exist on this collection instance." Do you know why?

Comment: Yup, cause `$proformaNumber` is a Collection of `Registration` Models, not a `Proforma`. You'd just need to do `dd($proformaNumber->first()->proforma)`;

Comment: No problem. Relationships can be confusing, especially when chained with others that have multiple. Work with em for a while and you'll start to understand the nuances. If you'd like this all written in an answer just let me know.

Comment: Thanks, yes you can answer so is possible to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using chained methods for accessing relationships, it should be easy to get a `Proforma` model for a given `Registraion` for a given `User`. Using the following:

```
$registration = $user->registrations()->with(["proforma"])->where("id", $regId)->first();
```

*Note, you can use `->get()` instead of `->first()` to access all registrations for the user as a `Collection`, then `->first()` to get the first one returned. In this situation, that doesn't make much sense as we have a specific `$regId` and are only expecting 1 registration.*

Then, to access the `Proforma` on the returned `Registration`, do the following:

```
$proforma = $registation->proforma;
```

There's many different ways to access relationships, and some caveats when trying to access relationships from a `Collection` vs a single `Model`, but this should provide some overall logic.